# How to make a class in a NodeJS addon return another addon?

Tags: node.js, v8

With this class I can make an instance of it in another addon's source. But how do I wrap the object and return it?

```
class foo : public ObjectWrap {
public:
  int mydata; // intentionally not exposed in node
  foo(){  mydata = 4; }
  static Persistent<Function> constructor;
  static void Init(){
    Local<FunctionTemplate> s = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
      s->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("foo"));
      s->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1); 
      constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(s->GetFunction());
    }

    static Handle<Value> NewInstance() {
        HandleScope scope;
        Local<Object> in = constructor->NewInstance();
        return scope.Close(in); 
    }

    static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args) {
        HandleScope scope;
        foo* f= new foo();
        f->Wrap(args.This());
        return scope.Close( args.This() );
    }
};
```

What I'd like to do is, from another classes method, make a new instance, and return it.

```
Handle<Value> bar_method( const Arguments& args ) {
    HandleScope scope;

    // make new instace of foo
    foo * f = new foo();
    f->mydata = 5;

    Handle<Object> obj = Object::New();
    obj->Set( String::New("property"), f??? );
    return scope.Close(obj);
}
```